How to load another property file for all @SpringBootTest and override defined default properties
I have several tests in my Springboot (Spring 6) application. Several are several SpringBootTests.
If I have src/test/resources/application.properties I need to duplicate the properties that is defined in src/main/resources/application.properties.
I would like to re-use the src/main/resources/application.properties in my test but only override some properties.
I could add a src/test/resources/application-myprofile.properties (or another profile) and add @ActiveProfiles("myprofile") to all my @SpringBootTest classes.
But I do not want to add this to every single @SpringBootTest class.
I tried to add a src/test/java/Config.java class with @TestPropertySource:
@Configuration 
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-myprofile.properties") 
public class
Config {

    public Config() {
        System.out.println("LOADING CONFIG");
    } 
}

I can see the 'LOADING CONFIG' getting printed, so the configuration class is loaded but it does not override my properties.
What am I doing wrong here?
UPDATE:
I added a sample project on GitHub.

Your approach with @ActiveProfile is the correct way. If you don't you will run into ordering issues of the loaded properties. Next to that I'm not even sure if @TestPropertySource even works on an @Configuration class, it works only on a test class (so if anything you should use a regular @PRopertySource and use @TestConfiguration instead of @Configuration although the latter will work.

I would suggest creating test specific configuration class and mark it with annotation @TestConfiguration. Lets say you call it TestConfig it may look like
@TestConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:api-test.properties")
public class TestConfig{
...
}

Note that there is another annotation @PropertySource where you list your properties file. And I suggest that you create separate properties file for testing even if you have to duplicate some of the properties from your main properties file.
Than your test file should be looking something like this:
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyService.class, TestConfig.class})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ApiServiceTest {

    @Resource
    private MyService myService;
...
}

In this case MyService is the class that you want to test. In @ContextConfiguration you can include other classes that you need for your test. But here you can see how in your TestConfig class you can add your own properties file

I tried doing this. Created a sample project here (https://github.com/Chrispie/code-problems/tree/override-properties-during-springboottest) with the suggested change but I am still something wrong here.
